# How can I change all div elements dir from LTR to RTL upon language selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the best way to change all div elements based on a language selection?

My scenario - viewing a web page in English, then changing to a right to left type language,

I want to add dir="rtl" on the fly and remove it or change it to dir="ltr" when a left to right type language is selected.

For example

```html
<div dir="ltr">
```

Comment: You can add a `css class` to all the `divs` you want change the direction, and set the `direction: ltr` in that class. Then using `jquery`, you can select all those `divs` and change their class to another class with `direction: rtl`

Comment: Its not clear if you're asking only how to change the class of those elements or what css to use in order to do the actual sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dropdown and attach change event handler. Within the handler callback update the attribute value.

**Using JQUERY :**

```js
$('#type').change(function() {
  $('#div').attr('dir', this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div" dir="ltr"></div>

<select id="type">
  <option value="ltl">left</option>
  <option value="rtl">right</option>
</select>
```

**Using Pure JS :**

```js
document.getElementById('type').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById('div').setAttribute('dir', this.value)
})
```

```html
<div id="div" dir="ltr"></div>

<select id="type">
  <option value="ltl">left</option>
  <option value="rtl">right</option>
</select>
```